# building forms in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using WordPress for building my own website and I want to building a form with blank space until users can fill the blanks and then submit the form. So the question is  which suitable plugin can I  use with this ability?

Answer (score 0):

I always use https://www.gravityforms.com as a developer.
If you don't have the money, try https://wpforms.com

And this is also a nice one https://wordpress.org/plugins/html-forms/

If you want  to do complex stuff and need to buy a license, then go for Gravity Forms, never failed me!